# How to create a transparent stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transparency

I'm trying to reproduce the iPhone battery symbol. It has a gap between the fill and the stroke. I successfully managed to do it with the appearance palette, as you can see below:

[image]

It works well if the background is white. However, once i put an image as a background...

[image]

I want the gap to be transparent, rather than white.

How can I do that?

Comment: Could the reason be that you selected "White" for the stroke color?

Comment: I selected white for the gap between the stroke and the fill, what i want is for this gap to be transparent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the opacity of your white stroke to 0, then check "Knockout Group" from the main transparency options of the path (not of the stroke itself).

Example:

[image]