# How to create invisible border line between two objects that are touching?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, borders

So, I have several objects that are touching. I want to create an invisible borderline between them. I know I could just move the object apart but then I lose the the right position of the object. Is there a way to do this?

[image: The line which I want to be the see through border]

Comment: Can you just add a stroke to that object ? If you want it invisible (which I don't understand) then use the fill color of that object ?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78740/how-to-create-a-transparent-stroke-in-illustrator | https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120622/set-white-lines-strokes-to-transparent-illustrator | https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27871/transparent-path-stroke-fill-in-illustrator

Comment: @Kyle No, it does not work. I want basically that line which I circeled to be a separation between the elements on the left and right. I can not just put the colour of the object because the object below is not just one colour but it is a picture.

Comment: How about [an offset path effect](https://imgur.com/ly4FP2H), set to a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

These are just *basic, general steps* regarding how to randomly remove a portion of a shape. What's shown below may not be exactly precise for your needs, but should cover the general methodology to utilize.

---

- Draw a secondary path with a stroke. 
  [image]
- Align this new stroke so it covers the area you want removed.
- Expand the stroke so it's a shape.
  [image]
- Select this new shape and the shapes you want to remove portions of.
- Use the **Shape Builder Tool** to remove that section.
  [image]

The **key** is to *align* the new shape properly with the underlying shape(s). (Or to correct the slivers of shapes which may result after Shape Builder due to improper alignment.)

---

There are other related questions here which may assist further:

- [How to create a transparent stroke in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78740/how-to-create-a-transparent-stroke-in-illustrator)
- [Set white lines & strokes to transparent [Illustrator]](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120622/set-white-lines-strokes-to-transparent-illustrator)
- [Transparent path/stroke fill in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27871/transparent-path-stroke-fill-in-illustrator)